# Coturn/turnserver : error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID (WebRTC)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, centos6, turn, coturn

I have this structure :

- Web server : Apache. it's in a LAN. It is on a pc (windows 7) which has public static ip. PC is in a network.
- Signal server: In a VM (VirtualBox Centos 6) on the same pc.
- STUN/TURN server : Coturn "4.5.0.4". In a VM (VirtualBox Centos 6) on the same pc.
- Client A : Laptop, Vista. I use a Samsung mobile and usb tethering to get (external) internet. The Mobile uses "mobile data" to connect to internet.
- Client B :Laptop, Windows 8(or Windows 10). I use a Samsung tablet and usb tethering to get (external) internet. The tablet uses "mobile data" to connect to internet.

I run a coturn/turnserver like this:

```
sudo turnserver -X xxx.xx.xxx.xx (this is my static external ip)
```

I have created port forward:

```
3479 -> 3478 for TCP
3479 -> 3478 for UTP
5348 -> 5349 for TCP
5348 -> 5349 for UTP
```

I use the default configuration file of coturn with these changes :

```
verbose
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
realm=mycompany.org
cert=server.crt
pkey=server.key
pkey-pwd=.... (it has been omitted)
log-file=/var/tmp/turnserver.log
simple-log
```

I have created files server.crt and server.key and i know they are right because i can use the web admin tool which need them to run with https

I have created admin user. I have created a key for user "test4" using :

```
sudo turnadmin -k -u test4 -r mycompany.org -p test
```

and i use it to create him :

```
sudo turnadmin -a -b "/var/db/turndb" -u test4 -r mycompamy.org -p ......
```

On client :

```
var STUN = {
    urls: "stun:xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3479" //port forward
};

var TURN = {
    urls: [
        "turn:xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3479?transport=udp", 
        "turn:xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3479?transport=tcp",
        "turn:xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3479"
    ], 
    username : "test4",
    credential : "......................", (it's the key. it has been omitted)
};
```

The messages, I get from coturn/turnserver are like these :

```
242: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 10.0.2.15:3478, remote addr 10.0.2.2:60113
242: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
242: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 10.0.2.15:3478, remote addr 10.0.2.2:60075
242: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
242: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
242: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
242: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
242: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
242: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
242: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
242: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
242: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
242: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
242: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
243: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
243: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
243: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
243: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
243: IPv4. Local relay addr: 10.0.2.15:55037
243: session 000000000000000003: new, realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>, lifetime=600
243: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
243: IPv4. Local relay addr: 10.0.2.15:52683
243: session 000000000000000002: new, realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>, lifetime=600
243: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
243: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
243: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
243: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
243: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
244: session 000000000000000002: refreshed, realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>, lifetime=0
244: session 000000000000000002: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
244: session 000000000000000003: refreshed, realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>, lifetime=0
244: session 000000000000000003: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
245: session 000000000000000002: closed (2nd stage), user <test4> realm <mycompany.org> origin <>, local 10.0.2.15:3478, remote 10.0.2.2:60113, reason: allocation timeout
245: session 000000000000000002: delete: realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>
245: session 000000000000000003: closed (2nd stage), user <test4> realm <mycompany.org> origin <>, local 10.0.2.15:3478, remote 10.0.2.2:60075, reason: allocation timeout
245: session 000000000000000003: delete: realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>
```

What am I missing here ? Why do I get "ICE failed" in console ?

I read in https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-behave-turn-08.html
about

```
"error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID"
```

it says

> 437 (Allocation Mismatch): This indicates that the client has picked a
>   5-tuple which the server sees as already in use or which was recently
>   in use. One way this could happen is if an intervening NAT assigned a
>   mapped transport address that was recently used by another allocation.
>   The client SHOULD pick another client transport address and retry the
>   Allocate request (using a different transaction id). The client SHOULD
>   try three different client transport addresses before giving up on
>   this server. Once the client gives up on the server, it SHOULD NOT try
>   to create another allocation on the server for 2 minutes.

What does this mean?

**UPDATE**

Now, when client A uses Chrome "49.02623.112 m" (I can't update it anymore because is on Vista) and client B "50.0.2661.75 m" the coturn server works fine for a few seconds. I run the server like this( I am not sure if this helps. XXX.XX.XXX.XX is the public static IP of the PC where the VM of the server lives and 192.168.2.190 is the internal IP) :

```
sudo turnserver -X XXX.XX.XXX.XX/192.168.2.190
```

These are the log messages:

```
0: log file opened: /var/log/turn_3205_2016-04-15.log
0:
RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Coturn-4.5.0.4 'dan Eider'
0:
Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 4096
0:
Due to the open files/sockets limitation,
max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 2000 (approximately)
0:

==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: DTLS 1.2 is not supported
0: TURN/STUN ALPN is not supported
0: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
0:
0: SQLite supported, default database location is /var/db/turndb
0: Redis supported
0: PostgreSQL supported
0: MySQL supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0:
0: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)

=====================================================

0: Config file found: /etc/turnserver/turnserver.conf
0: log file opened: /var/tmp/turnserver.log
0: Config file found: /etc/turnserver/turnserver.conf
0: Domain name:
0: Default realm: mycompany.org
0: Config file found: /etc/turnserver/server.crt
0: Config file found: /etc/turnserver/server.key
0: SSL23: Certificate file found: /etc/turnserver/server.crt
0: SSL23: Private key file found: /etc/turnserver/server.key
0: TLS1.0: Certificate file found: /etc/turnserver/server.crt
0: TLS1.0: Private key file found: /etc/turnserver/server.key
0: TLS1.1: Certificate file found: /etc/turnserver/server.crt
0: TLS1.1: Private key file found: /etc/turnserver/server.key
0: TLS1.2: Certificate file found: /etc/turnserver/server.crt
0: TLS1.2: Private key file found: /etc/turnserver/server.key
0: TLS cipher suite: DEFAULT
0: DTLS: Certificate file found: /etc/turnserver/server.crt
0: DTLS: Private key file found: /etc/turnserver/server.key
0: DTLS cipher suite: DEFAULT
0: NO EXPLICIT LISTENER ADDRESS(ES) ARE CONFIGURED
0: ===========Discovering listener addresses: =========
0: Listener address to use: 127.0.0.1
0: Listener address to use: 10.0.2.15
0: Listener address to use: ::1
0: =====================================================
0: Total: 1 'real' addresses discovered
0: =====================================================
0: NO EXPLICIT RELAY ADDRESS(ES) ARE CONFIGURED
0: ===========Discovering relay addresses: =============
0: Relay address to use: 10.0.2.15
0: Relay address to use: ::1
0: =====================================================
0: Total: 2 relay addresses discovered
0: =====================================================
0: pid file created: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0:   relay 10.0.2.15 initialization...
0:   relay 10.0.2.15 initialization done
0:   relay ::1 initialization...
0:   relay ::1 initialization done
0: Relay ports initialization done
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=1 created
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=0 created
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: Cannot create TLS listener
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 127.0.0.1:3479
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 127.0.0.1:5350
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 10.0.2.15:3478
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 10.0.2.15:3479
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 10.0.2.15:5349
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 10.0.2.15:5350
0: IPv6. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: ::1:3478
0: IPv6. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: ::1:3479
0: IPv6. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: ::1:5349
0: IPv6. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: ::1:5350
0: Total General servers: 2
0: IO method (admin thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: ERROR: Cannot create CLI listener
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: SQLite DB connection success: /var/db/turndb
1275: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 10.0.2.15:3478, remote addr 10.0.2.2:30637
1275: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
1275: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 10.0.2.15:3478, remote addr 10.0.2.2:30638
1275: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
1275: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1275: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1275: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1275: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1275: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
1275: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
1275: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1275: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1275: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1275: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1275: IPv4. Local relay addr: 10.0.2.15:52828
1275: session 001000000000000001: new, realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>, lifetime=600
1275: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
1275: IPv4. Local relay addr: 10.0.2.15:57360
1275: session 000000000000000001: new, realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>, lifetime=600
1275: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
1275: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
1275: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
1276: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1276: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1276: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1276: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1277: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1277: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1278: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1278: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1280: session 001000000000000001: refreshed, realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>, lifetime=0
1280: session 001000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
1280: session 000000000000000001: peer XXX.XX.XX.XX lifetime updated: 300
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
1280: session 000000000000000001: peer XXX.XX.XX.XX lifetime updated: 300
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
1280: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.2 lifetime updated: 300
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
1280: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.15 lifetime updated: 300
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1280: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.2 lifetime updated: 300
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
1280: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.15 lifetime updated: 300
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
1280: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.15 lifetime updated: 300
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
1280: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.15 lifetime updated: 300
1280: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
1281: session 001000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <test4> realm <mycompany.org> origin <>, local 10.0.2.15:3478, remote 10.0.2.2:30638, reason: allocation timeout
1281: session 001000000000000001: delete: realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>
1281: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.15 lifetime updated: 600
1281: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CHANNEL_BIND processed, success
1282: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.15 lifetime updated: 600
1282: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet CHANNEL_BIND processed, success
1282: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1283: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID
1285: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
1286: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
1286: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
1292: session 000000000000000001: refreshed, realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>, lifetime=0
1292: session 000000000000000001: realm <mycompany.org> user <test4>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
1293: session 000000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <test4> realm <mycompany.org> origin <>, local 10.0.2.15:3478, remote 10.0.2.2:30637, reason: allocation timeout
1293: session 000000000000000001: delete: realm=<mycompany.org>, username=<test4>
1293: session 000000000000000001: peer XXX.XX.XX.XX deleted
1293: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.2 deleted
1293: session 000000000000000001: peer 10.0.2.15 deleted
```

Comment: how are you running the TURN server on a public IP?

Comment: @mido . I'm not sure if i understand your question. I type: sudo turnserver -X xxx.xx.xxx.xx ( xxx.xx.xxx.xx is the public ip of the PC where the VM (centos 6) lives where turnserver lives)

Comment: that's my doubt, how are you sure that server is accessible from the public IP, usually I end up using AWS instance to run TURN on public ip, are you using similar set-up?

Comment: @mido. I have access to the "web admin tool" of coturn server from a laptop which is outside the network ( https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:5348 ) Does this prove that the server is accessible from the public ip?

Comment: probably, just wanted to confirm that, your laptop behind NAT by any chance?

Comment: @mido. I use Client A (Laptop, Vista. I use a Samsung mobile and usb tethering to get (external) internet.) to access the "web admin tool"

Comment: @mido. The IPs of Client A and Client B are in the 192.168.x.y range (probably because they are inside mobile company's network). When I use web tools which give the public IPs, I get another IP (public IP). So, I assumed the clients are behind NAT

Comment: I might be wrong but that might be an issue, usually when I am coturn on aws instance, I provide an internal ip and external ip in config before starting the server...

Comment: @mido. What do you mean? Can you make this more clear? What changes do i need to make to configuration file?

Comment: if you are behind a NAT, your internal ip would ip from NAT and external ip would be NAT's public ip, I am also not sure how reliable public ip from mobile networks would be

Comment: Right now I know which the clients are (and their internal/external IPs, development environment), but later the clients will be unknown (production) to me so I will not be able to provide their IPs. Am I right? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Please read the "UPDATE" section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a server on Centos 7 now, with 2 IP addresses and real certificate and "coturn" works. So maybe the solution was that now I use two IP addresses

Comment: Hey I'm getting this same error. ```incoming packet message processed, error 437: Mismatched allocation: wrong transaction ID```

what do you mean by 2 IP address, Is it 2 public IP to you server?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, it not such a good answer like "software **X** doesn't work, pick up software **Y**." However, in this case, it made my day. So If you can choose TURN-server software for your project, take a look at `reTurn` server.

Here are my story and answer.

After fighting with `coturn`: experimenting with settings, DBs, users, realms, and reading *tons of  DEBUG logs*. I've given up. I defeated.

I made a decision to switch to `reTurn` STUN/TURN-server. I followed this manual with minor modifications:
http://rtcquickstart.org/guide/multi/turn-reTurnServer.html

**Here are  stack details:**

- OS `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` in DigitalOcean

Install is simple `sudo apt-get install resiprocate-turn-server`.
You should note package has all pre-configuration steps *e.g. key generation*.

Here is meaningfull parts of my working `/etc/reTurn/reTurnServer.config` (everithing unocmmented including default settings)

```
TurnAddress = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
TurnPort = 3478
TlsTurnPort = 0
AltStunAddress = 0.0.0.0
AltStunPort = 0
LoggingType = file
SyslogFacility = LOG_DAEMON
LoggingLevel = INFO
LogFilename = /var/log/reTurnServer/reTurnServer.log
LogFileMaxLines = 10000 # May be usefull
Daemonize = true
PidFile = /var/run/reTurnServer/reTurnServer.pid
RunAsUser = return
RunAsGroup = return
AuthenticationRealm = reTurn
UserDatabaseFile = /etc/reTurn/users.txt
UserDatabaseHashedPasswords = false # For Development purposes it enougth
UserDatabaseCheckInterval = 5 # Check it every 5 seconds
NonceLifetime = 3600
AllocationPortRangeMin = 49152
AllocationPortRangeMax = 65535
DefaultAllocationLifetime = 600
MaxAllocationLifetime = 3600
TlsServerCertificateFilename = server.pem
TlsServerPrivateKeyFilename = server-key.pem
TlsTempDhFilename = /etc/reTurn/dh2048.pem
TlsPrivateKeyPassword =
```

and `/etc/reTurn/users.txt` (ony one record)

```
cloudguy:passw0rd:reTurn:AUTHORIZED
```

On a client side, I use `SimpleWebRTC` and `signalmaster` as a signal server.  How to tell the client to use out server:

```
peerConnectionConfig: {
  // I force browser to use relay
  iceTransports: 'relay',
  iceServers: [
    {
      url: "stun:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
    },
    {
      urls: [
        "turn:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3478?transport=udp",
        "turn:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3478?transport=tcp",
        "turn:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3478"
      ],
      credential: "passw0rd",
      username: "cloudguy"
    }
  ]
}
```

As result it works in the following cases:

- Two or three clients in the same LAN with NAT
- Two or three browsers in different LANs with NAT (!)
- Two or three clients in various LANs with NAT and ... **one of them with proxy** (Wow!)

So it works just like it should work. Yay. That is it. If you succeed with `coturn`, it is very curious to hear how you made this.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look and I will come back to you

Comment: in the installation text says "The host server1 in this example MUST have two IP addresses, in the example, 198.51.100.19 and 198.51.100.20. This is essential for the ICE/STUN/TURN protocols." . Have you done this to your server. I mean, does your server have 2 IP addresses?

Comment: @user1621010 two IP-addresses, I guess, for redundancy purposes, however in my case it works fine with only one interface. I think this is a limitation of Digital Ocean; their virtual machines have only one IP.

Comment: @user1621010 yes, that's entirely different and dedicated software, it doesn't need `coturn`

Comment: I type : "sudo service resiprocate-turn-server start" is this right?

Comment: @user1621010 `sudo service resiprocate-turn-server start` yes exactly

Comment: When I type : `sudo service resiprocate-turn-server status` , i get `reTurnServer dead but subsys locked` . I found this link [link] (http://serverfault.com/questions/26276/what-does-service-name-dead-but-subsys-locked-mean), so  I always delete the lock file /var/lock/subsys/reTurnServer, I start again the service, i stop the service and the lock file is there again. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: When i start the service, i get the message `Starting reTurnServer: INFO | 20160518-101234.650 |  | RETURN | 140694960662496 | ReTurnConfig.cxx:293 | Processed 1 user(s) from 22 line(s) in /etc/reTurn/users.txt`. Is this correct? Do you get I similar message? I ask all these questions because I haven't managed to have right communication, yet

Comment: I had problems with Centos 6 (in VirtualBox vm), so I installed reTurn on Centos7 server (NOT a VirtualBox vm) and worked

Comment: @user1621010 Sounds good! Is my understanding correct, are you able to use your TURN server? Have you checked it with WebRTC clients?

Comment: Yes, i did. Thank you

Comment: What about log file? The log file is always empty. Have you ever see anything written in the log file? I have changed the "LoggingLevel" from INFO to DEBUG